# How to Keep an array and dynamic Checkbox stays checked after submit?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have one dynamic checkbox (can be ++) that needs to stay checked after user submit.

I already tried some tricks like using a hidden input before my checkbox code in HTML. Now I stuck in doing an isset(_POST) and the checkbox didn't stay checked.

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_name[]" id="hidden_name0">                                                                

<input type="checkbox" name ="name[]" id="name0">

<label for="name">Name</label>
```

--------UPDATE--------
And in my PHP file, here's the code:

```
$valueName = array();
        if(isset($_POST["hidden_name"]))
        {
                    foreach($_GET['hidden_name'] as $value)
                {
                    array_push($valueName,$value);
                }
        }
```

That code doesn't work :/

How to make the checkbox stays checked after user check it and submit the form? What should I write in PHP? Do I really need a hidden input before my checkbox?

Comment: can you post more code. need to know how the post method work

Comment: i already updated the post :D

Comment: Are you updating the hidden field value with corresponding checkbox value?

Comment: you need to use isset for your checkbox itself instead of using hidden input.

Comment: i already do some research and if i use the hidden input to overwrite the value of checkbox, it will work. but mine can't work

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know how that works for you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) might be returning false since the submitted value is NULL. I suggest adding a `value='1'` on the hidden input field -- or are you updating that field with the corresponding checkbox value?

Alternatively, you have some other options:

1. Change the `name` for each dynamic checkbox to have an identifier.

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="name-x" <?php echo isset( $_POST['name-x'] ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
   ```

   Where `x` could be your dynamic ID. Notice the addition of the PHP code and using a ternary operator, you can check the checkbox if the `$_POST['name-x']` is set.
2. Add a value to the checkbox.

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" id="name0" value="name0" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" id="name1" value="name1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" id="name2" value="name2" />
   ```

   However, you need to match this value in your PHP code.

   ```
   <?php
   if ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) ) {
       $values = array();
       foreach( $_POST['name'] as $value ) {
           array_push( $values, $value );
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

   Then you have to modify your checkbox again to have inline PHP.

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" id="name0" value="name0" <?php echo in_array( "name0", $values ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
   <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" id="name1" value="name1" <?php echo in_array( "name1", $values ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
   <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" id="name2" value="name2" <?php echo in_array( "name2", $values ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
   ```

You can also create a function to display these inline codes to make it much cleaner. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you have a form that have some checkboxes and try to check which checkbox is checked. here is an example code

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name ="name[]" value="name1">

    <label for="name">Name 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name ="name[]" value="name2">

    <label for="name">Name 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name ="name[]" value="name3">

    <label for="name">Name 4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name ="name[]" value="name4">


    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the php code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $valueName = array();
        foreach($_POST['name'] as $value){
        array_push($valueName,$value);
        print_r($valueName);
    }
?>
```